# Qt: qSort without using the copy constructor

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qt4, qt4.8

As I understand the quicksort, if the shuffling of the members is done with the copy ctor, you're going to be pretty disappointed by what *O*(*n* ln *n*) really means. So I decided to test [`qSort`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qSort) with

```
QList<QObject> mylist;   //Yes, I know this isn't feasible, I just wanted to find where the copy ctor is being used
qSort(list);
```

and got hit with those

> 'QObject::QObject(const QObject&)' is private

errors. From what I can tell, the problem begins with the `begin()` method, because if I have

```
list.begin();
```

the compiler error indicates that this qlist.h line is somehow trying to use the copy ctor:

```
inline void detach() { if (d->ref != 1) detach_helper(); }
```

I realize I could make the list's members pointers, then implement the [`lessThan`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qSort-2) function, but that's not very convenient for this code base. So how can I avoid using the copy ctor when `qSort` operates on a list of objects?

I'm using Qt 4.8 on Linux 64-bit and 32-bit.

Comment: I don't use qt, but you could set up a set of indices numbered from 0 to the max number of items - 1.  Then you sort the indices instead of your list and use that to reference the data.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is that better than using pointers?

Comment: Yes it is "better" than pointers, since it doesn't need pointers.  I could post an answer, but it will be geared toward using `std::sort` and `vector`, not Qt (but the same principle would hold I would believe).

Comment: Documentation says that it _requires the item type to implement operator<()_. QObject doesn't implement it. I don't think that's a problem of copying honestly. Can you provide a minimal, yet complete example and post the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

I will take a stab at this, since I am not a Qt user.

In general, if you need to sort a list of objects that cannot be copied, or if the copying aspect is expensive, one workaround is to sort a list of indices instead of the data, and after the sorting is done, use the index list to access the data.

According to the docs for Qt's `qSort`, something like this may work using the method above:

```
int doSomething()
{
    QList<QObject> myList;
    //...
    QVector<int> index(myList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); ++i ) index[i] = i;
    qSort(index.begin(), index.end(), [](int n1, int n2) { return myList[n1] < myList[n2];});
}
```

Once this is done, you access the sorted `myList` container thusly:

```
myList[index[0]]; // First item
myList[index[1]]; // second item
...
```

Note:  I am assuming that `qSort` accepts a lambda function as the third argument.  If there are issues, you can use a function object.

Comment: That is essentially the same as sorting pointers, with the pointers being indices, except that there is less indirection with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator. This is by design.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator

So you just can't `qSort` a container with `QObject`s or derived classes, at least not in C++ before C++11. You could try switching on C++11 support (or higher) in your compiler (and make sure your Qt libs are compiled with that, too); if the Qt folks are as good as usual they're using [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics) in this case.

Else using pointers or perhaps one of the Qt pointer classes like `QSharedPointer` would be a valid way to go. And you'll need a `lessThan` operator or function anyway if you don't want the order to be by memory address.